# Windows Phone | Frame Based Animations And Memory Footprints

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, silverlight-4.0

I am developing a small game for Windows Phone which is based on silverlight animation.
Some animations are using silverlight animation framework like Trandforms API and some animations are frame based. What I am doing is, I am running a Storyboard having very small duration and when it;s completed event fires, I am changing image frame there. So images get replaced every time completed event get fired. But I think it is causing memory leakage in my game and memory footprint is increasing with time.

1. I want to ask is it a right way to do frame base animations or is there any better way to  do this in silverlight???
2. What I can do to reduce memory consumption so that it does not increase with time.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, beware animating anything which can't be GPU accelerated or bitmap cached. You haven't given enough information to tell if this is your issue but start by monitoring the frame rate counters, redraw regions and cache visualisation.

You can detect memory leaks with the built in profiling tools.
See DEBUG > Start Windows Phone Application Analysis